# Can we throw a keyboard interrupt in a QThread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread, keyboardinterrupt

I use a pyqt5 GUI to run a script in a QThread.
This script can catch and handle `KeyboardInterrupt`, and I want to trigger one on a button press for example.

Is it possible to emulate/throw a `KeyboardInterrupt` in the thread?

I am looking for something like this:

```
self.cancel_button.pressed.connect(self.throw_keyboard_interrupt)

self.thread = QThread()
.
.
.
self.thread.start()

def throw_keyboard_interrupt(self):
    self.thread."throw keyboard interrupt into thread"()
```

Comment: When you say "run a script", do you mean your thread starts a separate process?  You can certainly send a SIGINT signal to another process, but signals are process things, not thread things.  If you send yourself a SIGINT, it affects your process.

Comment: yes, in a separate thread.
I am making a GUI to control a script that is made to handle keyboard interrupts
I wand to have a button "cancel" that triggers this keyboard interrupt

Comment: Did you read my question?  Because you didn't answer it.  Is your thread starting another process (with `subprocess`, for example), or are you just running a local Python function?

Comment: sorry, it is just a (Q)thread, not a process. but if you have a solution that works with processes, I am interested in that too. I can move to a process implementation

Comment: You can use `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)` to send a keyboard interrupt to a process.  And I lied a little bit; there is an API (pthread_kill) to send a signal to a thread, but I've never seen it exposed to Python.